# strange symbol in file created with bash

Tags: bash

When I execute bash script below. I got strange name file in output

```
#!/bin/bash  
for file in `cat *and*.txt` 
do
./AT.pl $1 $2 $file  | sed 's/ //g'  > $file
done
```

Output below:

```
Dio_Cfg.h
Dio_Cfg.h_1?
Dio_Cfg.h_12?
Dio_Cfg.h_13?
Dio_Cfg.h_14?
```

When I replace "./AT.pl $1 $2 $file  | sed 's/ //g'  > $file" with echo command. the result is normal.

I don't know where is this come from? Please help me

Thank you,
Tam Nguyen

Comment: It comes from `AT.pl` script? What is the `AT.pl` script output? Sidenotes: doing `for file in cat` is [bad](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and using \` \` for command substitution is [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) and [not quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) your variables `"$1" "$2" "$file"` might result in invalid/unwanted output.

Comment: Please show me the good way to replace for command

Comment: Sure: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Use `while read -r line; do ... done < <(cat *and*.txt)` ; )

Comment: Anyway, what is the expected output of you script? How are you viewing the file (using vim)? Is this a non-ascii special character or it's just `?` ? And what is the output of `AT.pl` string? Can you give an example of input file?